# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'variable' of null

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

Can you tell me why if I use this code within a simple web page, I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Shubby' of null

```js
var galleryText = ["A", "B", "C"];
galleryText["A"] = [
    "A A",
    "A B"
];
galleryText["B"] = [
    "B A",
    "B B",
    "B C"
];
galleryText["C"] = [
    "C A",
    "C B"
];

var currentGallery = "B";
var currentText = 0;

console.log(galleryText[currentGallery][currentText]);
```

I'm a JS neophyte, and unfortunately I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: "A" is not the index of your array is just a value stored inside the array

Comment: what is Shubby actually?

Comment: The code you provided here doesn't produce the error you have described in your question

Answer (score 0):

You have to use :

```js
galleryText[0] = [
   "A A",
   "A B"
];
galleryText[1] = [
   "B A",
   "B B",
   "B C"
];
galleryText[2] = [
   "C A",
   "C B"
];
var currentGallery = 1;
var currentText = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`galleryText` should be an object:

```js
var galleryText = {};
galleryText["A"] = [
    "A A",
    "A B"
];
galleryText["B"] = [
    "B A",
    "B B",
    "B C"
];
galleryText["C"] = [
    "C A",
    "C B"
];

var currentGallery = "B";
var currentText = 0;

console.log(galleryText[currentGallery][currentText]);
```